# How to define own colors for matplotlib pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code to plot values on my map. My dataset are values from 0 - 10.

```
# plot the data (first layer)
im1 = m.pcolormesh(xx, yy, data.T, cmap=plt.get_cmap('PiYG'))
```

Is there a way to define the color for the values. 
Like 0 -> red, 1 -> blue, ... ?

Comment: I think it's like this? cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['#ff0000', '#0000ff', ...])